# How to reduce the APK size to upload on Google Play?

Tags: android

I generate the singned apk and i tried to upload it ,I find this problem help me please

[image]

Comment: Please use only English for question and title on this site

Comment: Don't include 200 picture in high definition ? > 100Mo is a huge APK...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

First of all be sure that all your assets/drawable are of the right dimension and with a good compression.

Then if you are using libraries like google play services or firebase don't include the all library but only the portion of library you are using.

For example don't include all google play services in all single implementation/compile section but if you use only vision and map use only this two implementation/compile

**NOT:**

```
implementation 'implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

**BUT INSTEAD:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
```

Last but not least, if you have some content that your users can download from internet, don't include it on your apk but let them download it from the net and save on storage.